# recode variables with NAs with ifelse() in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am recoding two binary variables into new variable such that any 1s in the first variable take a 0 in the new one and all digits in the second variable are preserved. The code below shows the logic that I would like to produce. However, when I run this code, the recoding using the ifelse() just recreates x2 without incorporating the first ifelse() line that uses x1's 1s as 0. Thoughts?

```
set.seed(123)
x1 <- sample(c(0,1,NA), 20, replace = TRUE)
x2 <- sample(c(0,1,NA), 20, replace = TRUE)

recode <- ifelse(x1 == 1, 0, NA)
recode <- ifelse(x2 == 1, 1, recode)
recode <- ifelse(x2 == 0, 0, recode)

table(recode); table(x2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
ifelse(is.na(x2), ifelse(x1 == 1, 0, NA), x2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but it does what you wanted to do. The problem that you might have forgotten is that the result of comparison of NA with anything is also NA, so `ifelse( x2 == 0, yes, no )` returns NA (instead of `no`) if `x2 == NA`.

Better try

```
recode <- rep( NA, length( x1 ) )
recode[ x1 == 1 ] <- 0
recode[ ! is.na( x2 ) ] <- x2[ ! is.na( x2 ) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You overwrote those results. The relevant line from the Details section of the help('ifelse') page is:

```
 Missing values in test give missing values in the result.

recode <- ifelse(x1 == 1, 0, NA)
recode[ !is.na(x2)] <- x2[!is.na(x2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this just to figure out if there is some reason this one liner was not suggested:

```
recode <- ifelse(x1 %in% 1 & is.na(x2), 0, x2)
```